# exception on making toast in android

Tags: android, json, toast

I am implementing a code in android that sends json data to server.I am referring to the tutorials of the following link :-
   [sending json to server.](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/)

Almost all the code works fine, i.e. i am getting response from server.But when my code reaches **onPostExecute()**  method I get the following exception :

```
01-18 02:20:40.485      435-435/com.example.sagar.postjson W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-18 02:20:40.505      435-435/com.example.sagar.postjson E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
            at com.example.sagar.postjson.HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HttpAsyncTask.java:119)
            at com.example.sagar.postjson.HttpAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HttpAsyncTask.java:26)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code for this method is as follows :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getBaseContext(), "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have also tried in this way :-

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     new MainActivity().print();
}
```

print() method in MainActivity as :

```
public void print(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But it also doesn't works.

Please tell me where i am wrong,,
Thanks.

Comment: Try this: Toast.makeText( this, "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Your context object needs to be the current activity or application context. If you can not reach it because you made your AsyncTask an external class then you need to pass you context in when you construct your AsyncTask. (or create a static way to get your context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is this piece of code:

```
new MainActivity().getBaseContext()
```

This is not a way how to obtain **Context**. You need to change it to **MainActivity.this** and then it will work (it depends on current scenario as well and i don't know yours).

> No , i have defined in the same package as MainActivity but didn't
>   made it inner class.

Since your **AsyncTask** *is separated class it knows nothing* about your Activity class. You need to pass Context through constructor:

```
public MyTask(final Context context) {
   this.mContext = context;
}
```

Usually I'm showing toast messages by implementing util method that will do it for me:

```
public static void showMessage(final String msg) {
   final Context context = App.getContext();
   Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

where App is custom class that extends from Application and it could like like:

```
public class App extends Application {

   private static Context sContext;

   public void onCreate() {
      sContext = getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getContext() {
      return sContext;
   }
}
```

I think it's better way how to do it and also it's more clean solution since you can call it everywhere in your application without redundant calls.

Comment: I had just tried using MainActivity.this but android studio is showing error : MainActivity is not an enclosing class. :(

Comment: @sagar where you have your AsyncTask class? It's inner class of Activity class?

Comment: No , i have defined in the same package as MainActivity but didn't made it inner class.

Comment: Though it works for me but i am wondering why my second approach didn't worked that i mentioned in question i.e.  calling print method of MainActivity by new MainActivity().print() , can we not call activities just like classes??

Comment: @sagar in Android there is no such a `new MainAcitivity()`. Activities works differently than normal classes. Look at Activity lifecycles in official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Toast` to be...

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity().getActivity(), "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

instead of...

```
Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getBaseContext(), "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You do not need to create a new `Activity`, only reference the `Context` of the current `Activity`.

Comment: I tried to use that you have just told me in android studio, but its giving error , - MainActivity is not an enclosing class.

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I have tried using both; MainActivity().getActivity() - Its giving - method call expected.    and by MainActivity.getActivity() - its giving, can not resolve method getActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69040/discussion-between-sagar-and-willis).

Answer (score 1):

Define a global variable in the Class `Context mcontext;`

Then , in `oncreate()` initialize the variable `mcontext= getActivity().getApplicationContext()` .

Then, use the context in that class .

```
Toast.makeText(mcontext, "come", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```